# Json to pojo when our json have a linkedTreeMap Android

Tags: android, json, dictionary, gson

I have a json at bellow format.

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "ride.success.init",
"items": {
    "cargos": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "بسته",
            "status": 1,
            "description": "بسته کوچک"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "پاکت",
            "status": 1,
            "description": "پاکت نامه"
        },
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "بسته بزرگ",
            "status": 1,
            "description": "بسته ۱ در ۱ متر"
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is cargos object. when I use the http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it creates bellow classes:

```
public class _1 {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
public int id;
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
public String title;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
public int status;
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
public String description;
```

}

How can I prevent _1 and _2 and _3 classes?
What is the correct type for Cargos Items?

Comment: Please provide your actual code in text form. Screenshots make it difficult to work with your data and code.

Comment: No-one wants to see pictures of your code. Code is text, so please include it here as text. Then people can copy and use it for an answer. In any case it surely is quicker to copy/paste than to upload an image?

Comment: Thanks, I edited @Barns

Comment: The JSON has an odd structure. I would expect for "cargos" to be a JSONArray. More like this:    "cargos": [{"id": 1,"title": "بسته","status": 1,description": "بسته کوچک"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "پاکت",
            "status": 1,
            "description": "پاکت نامه"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "بسته بزرگ",
            "status": 1,
            "description": "بسته ۱ در ۱ متر"
        }]  -- Notice the "1","2","3" are now not necessary. Now you can use the "id" key